# Lua script for statistics from Diameter 3GPP

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector, diameter-protocol

I'm trying to create a lua script to go through a Diameter pcap, gather information interesting for me and generate a statistic.

This is partially successful, working script can be found in [GitHub](https://github.com/jaroslawhartman/wiresharkLUA) but I'm still having some doubts

### Field.new() and multiple occurrences of an AVP

I'm using `Field.new()` to retrieve AVPs, for example:

```
local rrField = Field.new("diameter.3GPP-Reporting-Reason")
local toField = Field.new("diameter.CC-Total-Octets")
```

But in a single packet there might be multiple occurrences of an AVP. Of course, I can access them as an array from

```
local rrFields = {rrField()}
local toFields = {toField()}
```

But I'm missing a reference *where from* the AVP was retrieved. A a good example is `Result-Code AVP`:

[image: image description]

It this single Diameter message it occurs three times, but in result I'm getting just an array of three 2001's without a good understanding on which level this appeared.

Situation is becoming even more messy when a single package contains *multiple* Diameter messages. Then I even cannot figure from which *message* the AVP is.

### Function tap.packet(pinfo, tvb, tapdata) does not populate tapdata

Another idea was to dig into `tapdata`. If I understood correctly [11.4.1.5. listener.packet](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/lua_module_Listener.html#lua_class_Listener), the `tapdata` (aka `tapinfo`) shall be populated with dissected data, right? Hence I should be able to parse the message.

However, regardless how hard I try, `tapdata` always is unset (i.e. nil). In GitHub code

```
       tap = Listener.new("diameter", filter)
```

but I also experimented with the 3rd parameter, setting it to `true` (hoping for generating all fields, even in cost of performance penalty). No luck.

**[Update 2020/03/20]**

Self-answering to `Function tap.packet(pinfo, tvb, tapdata) does not populate tapdata`

After examining source code of Wireshark (tshark) it turns out that Diameter does not populate this variable as tapdata does not have reference to Diameter. I've tried to add it to `taps` definition and the variable (table) has been populated, even names of the hashes are OK. But variables in the hashes are not... Anyway, here is the change:

```
MBP:wireshark jhartman$ git diff epan/wslua/taps
diff --git a/epan/wslua/taps b/epan/wslua/taps
index 11b1132171..ea28865109 100644
--- a/epan/wslua/taps
+++ b/epan/wslua/taps
@@ -62,4 +62,5 @@ tcp ../dissectors/packet-tcp.h tcp_info_t
 #tls ../dissectors/packet-tls.h ssl_info_t
 #tr ../dissectors/packet-tr.h tr_info_t
 wlan ../dissectors/packet-ieee80211.h wlan_hdr_t
+diameter ../dissectors/packet-diameter.h diam_sub_dis_t
 #wsp ../dissectors/packet-wsp.h wsp_info_t
```

### Question

- Is this approach right? Or should I use other ways - such as chained dissectors or post dissector? But it was not clear to me if I can access dissected data to the level I need?

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thank you in advance and best regards,
Jarek